# Last iteration with istream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, fstream

I use a `std::istream_iterator` to iterate over my read in binary file and now I want to recognize the last iteration of the for loop! How can I do this?

```
std::ifstream fwImage("file.img", std::ios::in | ios::binary);

typedef std::istream_iterator<BYTE> input_iterator;
for(input_iterator it(fwImage); it!=input_iterator(); it++)
{
    // need a check when input_iterator is in his last iteration -> end of file    
}
```

Comment: What do you need to do on the last iteration? I would just store whatever the previously read thing was, then when you hit `eof`, access your previously read thing.

Comment: @nchen24 Ok! Do you have an example? (based on my code) Thx

Comment: I've never used `istream_iterator` before, so I can't exactly provide you with an example.  I'm still unclear on what exactly you want to do, though, just print out/use the last thing before the eof?

Comment: @nchen24 I have a buffer with size of 1000 bytes and have to send it also at last iteration (e.g. only 800 bytes) -> I use a byte counter with if statement (if(counter == 1000) send and clear the buffer)! Hope it is clear now!?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use a circular buffer, exit the loop when you hit eof, then return the circular buffer?  If you clear every 1000 bytes, then if your input is, say, 2015 bytes, you'll only get 15 bytes of information, rather than the last 1000.

Comment: @nchen24 Maybe its better, yes! I will rewrite my code! Thx you anyway for your help! ;-)